# Visualização de PDF com jQuery

Tags: jquery, pdf, otimização

Preciso exibir um PDF como se fosse uma revista dentro de uma pagina HTML. A ideia é otimizar a visualização de um documento que está bem pesado(+100 paginas).

Atualmente só tenho um link que abre o arquivo em outra aba, e está demorando muito para carregar.

Encontrei um plugin chamado TurnJS. Mas nunca usei.
Vocês já utilizaram esse plugin? Conhece uma solução melhor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recomendo o [PDFObject](https://github.com/pipwerks/PDFObject) aproveite e leia também as [instruções](http://pdfobject.com/instructions.php) para o uso do mesmo.

O melhor que eu já usei, além de ser o mais leve pela minha opinião.